Ubuntu 24.04.1 sleep mode not working
I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 laptop with an Nvidia RTX 3050 GPU. I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.1. On Windows, when I lock my computer with the Windows + L key combination or close the lid, the battery barely drains overnight. However, when I do the same on Ubuntu, I find that almost half of the battery is drained by the next morning.
Additionally, during regular use, the battery life on Ubuntu is significantly shorter compared to Windows. How can I improve this? Are there any settings or recommendations to help extend battery life and reduce power consumption?
Thank you!

It sounds like your computer is not fully shutting down. To see what is going on, note the time, close the lid, wait 60 seconds, open the lid, issue the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" (supply your login password when prompted). Adjust the -5 minutes to cover the time I had you remember. Carefully read each log entry.

I couldn't understand the result also I can't type whole result here. I will share drive link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1t5__sglD9BEcz84llfFIHuPHTk1D-I/view?usp=drive_link

Did you read each line? Several suggest ("Hibernation is restricted") you read man kernel_lockdown. You'll probably have to change something in your BIOS. Ensure you have  a RAM-sized, contiguous swap area. Reading logs is a necessary skill. Each message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger for ONE way of producing log messages.
